# how to print a PCB layout for UV etching

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, uv

I am new to UV etching. I have a 2 layer PCB layout that I prepared on Eagle Cad. I am confused what layer do I need to mirror?

After printing the layout what side of the paper turns to the UV light and to the board (for both top and bottom layers)?

Edit: I use [Jetstar inkjet film](http://uk.farnell.com/mega/100-070/jetstar-film-a4-pk10/dp/4138090?Ntt=4138090) (transparent) and I will use ink printer (HP). I will use UV box to transfer the layout onto the PCB.

Comment: Paper? Not transparencies?

Comment: What method are you using? Toner transfer?

Comment: You can reason this out for yourself: the toner must be pressed against the copper, hence the bottom side must be 'true', and the top side must be 'inverted'. BUT if you have never done this before I suggest you start with a 1-sided pcb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have printed ink as close to the PCB surface as possible. In order to do so you need to mirror the top layer.

[image]